# static memory allocation like dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, declaration, stdvector, variable-length-array

Code:

```
int r, c;
cin >> r >> c;
int matrix[r][c];
```

I don't understand the idea behind runtime allocation. The aim is to allocate memory during runtime but in the above section of code we are doing the same.

When this part of code is run, the inputs sizes are given during runtime and matrix is allocated memory according to the size of rows and columns, so how is it static or compile time allocation?

Comment: That's a compiler extension that regularly creates a little confusion on who's learning the language

Answer (score 3):

This declaration

```
int r, c;
cin >> r >> c;
int matrix[r][c];
```

is a declaration of a variable length array.

This array has automatic storage duration. And the array is created at run-time when the values of the variables `r` and `c` will be known.

However variable length arrays are not a standard C++ feature.

Instead of the array you could use the standard container std::vector like

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix( r, std::vector<int>( c ) );
```

In this case all elements of the matrix will be zero-initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Static but allocated at runtime.

Static allocation is fixed size and occurrs on the fast but small stack:

```cpp
int a = 0;
```

Dynamic allocation can be dynamically sized but it is not performat to allocate small thing on the heap:

```cpp
int* a = new int(0);
```

Only dynamic memory can be passed to different scopes but you need to `delete` it when you're done.

Comment: You can perform *dynamic* (dynamic size) memory allocation on stack using `alloca` function. It's not part of the ANSI-C standard but it is widely supported.
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html

Comment: @MarcinPoloczek Great! I didn't knew that!